# How to pass styles Props to child components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

I need to pass Props in the Style so that each component has a different background image.

I have this component:

countries.astro

```
---
import type { Props } from 'astro';
const { country, description } = Astro.props as Props;
---

<section>
    <div>
        <h1>{country}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
</section>

<style>
    section {
        height: 100vh;
        color: #fff;
    }

    div {
        height: 100%;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;

    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 8rem;
    }
</style>
```

And I want to have a different background image in the index, depending on the country:

index.astro

```
---
import Countries from "../components/Countries.astro";

import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
---

<Layout title="Countries">
    <Countries country="ITALY"/>
    <Countries country="SPAIN"/>
    <Countries country="GERMANY"/>
</Layout>

<style>

</style>
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set different background images for the `Countries` components in your `index.astro` file based on the country, you can pass a `style` prop to the `Countries` component and use conditional CSS classes. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. Modify your `Countries.astro` component to accept a `style` prop, which will determine the background image:

```
---
import type { Props } from 'astro';
const { country, description, style } = Astro.props as Props;
---

<section class={`country-section ${style}`}>
    <div>
        <h1>{country}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
</section>

<style>
    section.country-section {
        height: 100vh;
        color: #fff;
    }

    /* Define different background images based on the style prop */
    section.country-section.italy {
        background-image: url('italy.jpg');
    }

    section.country-section.spain {
        background-image: url('spain.jpg');
    }

    section.country-section.germany {
        background-image: url('germany.jpg');
    }

    /* Add more country-specific styles as needed */
    
    div {
        height: 100%;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 8rem;
    }
</style>
```

2. In your `index.astro`, pass the `style` prop to each `Countries` component based on the country:

```
---
import Countries from "../components/Countries.astro";
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
---

<Layout title="Countries">
    <Countries country="ITALY" style="italy" />
    <Countries country="SPAIN" style="spain" />
    <Countries country="GERMANY" style="germany" />
</Layout>

<style>
    /* Define any global styles for your index page if needed */
</style>
```

In this setup, you're passing the `style` prop to each `Countries` component, and in the `Countries.astro` component, you apply different background images based on the `style` prop using conditional CSS classes. Each country-specific section will have its own background image defined in the CSS, which will be loaded based on the style prop passed from the index.

Comment: Amazing!!! It is work!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped @PilaGonzalez